Derivation of the BRST invariance in QCD
I am trying to follow the proof for the BRST invariance in QCD in the following pdf file: https://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph222/BRST.pdf (section 3, from end of page 6)
I can understand the derivations up to line above equation 45, where I am not sure exactly how this expression is obtained.
To be more precise, here is how I guessed the derivation is done:
In order to define a generalized gauge symmetry, the following term is added to the Lagrangian:
$$L_{G} = - \eta_{a} (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b})$$
where the infinitessimal transformations of $\eta_{a}$ and $\omega_{a}$ are given by: $$\delta \eta_{a} = -\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu}_{a}\tag{41}$$  and $$\delta \omega_{a} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{abc} \omega_{b}\omega_{c}.\tag{44}$$
Using these, we have:
$\delta L_{G} = - (\delta \eta_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \eta_{a} \left(\partial^{\mu}\delta (D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b})\right) = (\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \eta_{a} \left(\partial^{\mu} (\delta D^{ab}_{\mu}) \omega_{b}\right) - \eta_{a} \left(\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu} (\delta \omega_{b})\right)$
Given the formula for $D^{ab}_{\mu}$ in equation (36) and the one for $(\delta A^{a}_{\mu})$ in equation (35), I can find $(\delta D^{ab}_{\mu})$ as:
$\delta D^{ab}_{\mu} = \delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \delta + gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right]$
Hence,
$\delta L_{G} = (\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \eta_{a} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \delta \omega_{b} + gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right]\omega_{b} \right) - \eta_{a} \left(\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu} (\delta \omega_{b})\right)$
$\delta L_{G} = (\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \eta_{a} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{bcd} \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right] + gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right]\omega_{b} \right) - \eta_{a} \left(\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{bcd} \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right)$
$\delta L_{G} = (\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \eta_{a} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{bcd} \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right] + gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right]\omega_{b} + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{bcd} D^{ab}_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right)$
$\delta L_{G} = (\frac{\epsilon}{a}\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}_{a}) (\partial^{\mu}D^{ab}_{\mu}\omega_{b}) - \frac{1}{2} g \eta_{a} \epsilon f^{bcd} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right) - \eta_{a} \partial^{\mu}\left(  gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right]\omega_{b} + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon g f^{bcd} D^{ab}_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right)$
Now, a quick look at the equation (45) and the equality that precedes it tells me that, if I did not make any mistakes above, then $\frac{1}{2} g \eta_{a} \epsilon f^{bcd} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right) = 0$. However, I am not sure exactly how to prove that this is the case. I know that the structure coefficients are fully antisymmetric and that $\omega_{c}$ are anticommuting fields, but still...
Here is my attempt:
$f^{bcd} \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right) = \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} f^{bcd} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right) = - \partial^{\mu} \left(\delta^{ab} f^{bdc} \partial_{\mu} \left[ \omega_{c}\omega_{d} \right]\right)$
where I use $f^{bcd} = -f^{bdc}$. Now, if we had $\omega_{c}\omega_{d} = \omega_{d}\omega_{c}$, then I could make the switch and simply relabel the indices resulting in an expression as $x = -x \implies x = 0$. But since $\omega_{c}$ anti-commutes, we have $\omega_{c}\omega_{d} = -\omega_{d}\omega_{c}$ which would simply cancel the negative sign from the structure coefficients and I would just end up with the original expression. So that's where I don't know how to proceed.
I unfortunately do not see how this expression can be shown to be zero and would appreciate it if someone could tell me where I am going wrong and what I am missing.

Your problem is that your equation
$$
\delta D^{ab}_{\mu} = \delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \delta + gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right],
$$
is wrong. The correct version is
$$
\delta D^{ab}_{\mu} = gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right].
$$
To see this, we can look at how $D$ acts on a function $h$:
\begin{align*}
\delta (D^{ab}_{\mu}h) &= \delta \left(\delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu}h + gf^{abc} A_{\mu}^c h \right),\\
&= \delta^{ab} \partial_{\mu} \delta h + g f^{abc} A_{\mu}^c (\delta h) + g f^{abc} (\delta A_{\mu}^c) h,\\
&= D^{ab}_{\mu} \delta h + g f^{abc} (\delta A_{\mu}^c) h.
\end{align*}
But we also have that $\delta (D^{ab}_{\mu}h) = D^{ab}_{\mu} \delta h + \delta (D^{ab}_{\mu}) h$, so we identify
$$
\delta D^{ab}_{\mu} \equiv g f^{abc} (\delta A_{\mu}^c) = gf^{abc}\left[\epsilon D^{cd}_{\mu} \omega_{d} \right].
$$
